# Avoiding the extra discussion of the zero ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

To see more example of the kind below, see the nlab page [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple).

*All rings mentioned below are commutative and unital.*

When working with commutative unital rings, one usually cannot avoid the discussion of the "zero ring" as trying to make the argument fully rigorous. As a simple example, consider the assertion below:

> **False Assertion**. A ring $A$ is a field iff every homomorphism $A\to B$ is injective.

The assertion is false as $0\to B$ is always injective but the ring $0$ is not a field. Also for any field $A$, $A\to 0$ is never injective at all. After excluding the two zero ring cases, the assertion is true(stated below:)

> **Correct Assertion**. A **non-zero** ring $A$ is a field iff every homomorphism $A\to B$ to a **non-zero** ring $B$ is injective.

Most the results for commutative rings involve a redundant discussion of the zero ring case but as far as I know, none of the definitions nor results in commutative algebra depends on the use of zero ring. As the category of commutative rings is not even an additive category, we cannot chase diagram of rings like modules.

The ring $0$ provides with no insights as counterexamples as well, since it is excluded from most results and definitions. From all perspective it is almost always useless. **For a more simplified paragraph and argument, is it wise to put "all rings mentioned below are assumed to be non-zero" whenever working with them?**

Or are there better ways around?

Comment: So for example, if you wanted to work with tensor products of rings, would you also assume that you never form a tensor product which ends up being the zero ring?  e.g. $(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z})$

Comment: @DanielSchepler In your example we only have to treat the tensor product as $\Bbb Z$-modules to show the result is $0$. The only possible way for $0$ to be a ring is for it to be the zero ring. I would say the key lies in the $\Bbb Z$-modules part, not the rings part.

Comment: I think you are fighting a lost cause. One could equally well argue that the zero ring should be considered to be a field (since a nice, but incorrect, definition of a field is a ring in which all non-zero elements are invertible). I also think that your claim that most results have to exclude the zero ring is dubious: do you have any firm evidence for it?

Comment: _For a more simplified paragraph and argument, is it wise to put "all rings mentioned below are assumed to be non-zero" whenever working with them?_ You could also just simply say "has identity $1\neq 0$" to rule them out.

Comment: The approach mentioned by rschwieb (requiring $1 \ne 0$) is the most common one I think. Of course one should then also require ring maps to send $1$ to $1$

Comment: @DanielSchepler I see nothing wrong with the statement that the category of rings need not admit all tensor products

Comment: There are similar false assertions for sets ("a set $X$ is a singleton iff every function to $X$ is surjective") and groups ("a group $G$ is simple iff every homomorphism from $G$ is injective"), so this particular example seems as much an argument against the empty set and trivial group as it does against the zero ring.